# How do I Update only Sheet1 of a workbook template...?

Tags: templates, vba, excel

I have this code to copy data from a range in one workbook to Sheet1 of a specific template. ( The data from Sheet1 then populates a second sheet in the template file.) Each file is created and named for the names in the range “names1”.

This seems to work perfectly, but I need it to do two other things:

- Firstly, I need it to check and see if a file has already been created with the filename, and if so, not to overwrite it, or prompt for saving.
- Secondly, and most importantly, I need to find a way to have it check for an existing file, and then ONLY overwrite Sheet1 with the info from above, WITHOUT changing anything on any of the other sheets in the file, and then save and close the file. And then continue checking all the other names in the file, and either creating a new file from the template (as my code already does) OR updating only sheet1 and saving/closing the file.

I have searched for help on this, but with my limited VBA knowledge, I’m not sure where to put the add-ins and what syntax to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is my working code:

```
Sub Smart1()

Dim src As Workbook
Dim dst As Workbook
SavePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set src = ActiveWorkbook

For Each C In Range("Names1")

i = C.Row

Name = Cells(i, 44).Value
PSFFAll = Cells(i, 45).Value
CLSFall = Cells(i, 46).Value
CLSWin = Cells(i, 47).Value
CLSEnd = Cells(i, 48).Value
WWRFall = Cells(i, 49).Value
WWRWin = Cells(i, 50).Value
WWREnd = Cells(i, 51).Value
DORFWin = Cells(i, 52).Value
DORFEnd = Cells(i, 53).Value
AccWin = Cells(i, 54).Value
AccEnd = Cells(i, 55).Value

fname = Cells(i, 44).Value & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Open FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Smart1.xlsx"

With Workbooks("Smart1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
.Range("a2").Value = Name
.Range("B2").Value = PSFFAll
.Range("C2").Value = CLSFall
.Range("D2").Value = CLSWin
.Range("E2").Value = CLSEnd
.Range("F2").Value = WWRFall
.Range("G2").Value = WWRWin
.Range("H2").Value = WWREnd
.Range("I2").Value = DORFWin
.Range("J2").Value = DORFEnd
.Range("K2").Value = AccWin
.Range("L2").Value = AccEnd
End With

ActiveWorkbook.saveas FileName:=SavePath & "\" & fname
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
On Error Resume Next

Next C

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer only for your first question. Use this to check if a file exists.

```
Sub saveme()

    SavePath = "D:\folder"
    fname = "test.xls"
    fullsavepath = SavePath & "\" & fname

    On Error Resume Next
    If Dir(fullsavepath) <> "" Then
        Open fullsavepath For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1: Close #1
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        If MsgBox("A file with the name '" & fname & "' is already open." & vbCrLf & _
            "Do you want to replace it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, _
            "Microsoft Excel") = vbYes Then

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Workbooks(fname).Close savechanges:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fullsavepath
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If

    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fullsavepath
    End If

    Err.Clear

End Sub
```

The important part is:

```
If Dir(fullsavepath) <> "" Then
    Open fullsavepath For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1: Close #1
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  How would I insert this into my current code?

Comment: With my current code, I do get a window that tells me the file already exists, and prompts for overwriting.  I want to NOT get a prompt, and only have it IGNORE when the file already exists, and just continue with creating the new files.  I REALLY need to figure out how to update only the SHEET1 of the existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer!
Thanks to Tweedle!
Sub Smart1()
    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim dst As Workbook
    SavePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

```
Set src = ActiveWorkbook


For Each C In Range("Names1")


    i = C.Row


    Name = Cells(i, 44).Value
    PSFFAll = Cells(i, 45).Value
    CLSFall = Cells(i, 46).Value
    CLSWin = Cells(i, 47).Value
    CLSEnd = Cells(i, 48).Value
    WWRFall = Cells(i, 49).Value
    WWRWin = Cells(i, 50).Value
    WWREnd = Cells(i, 51).Value
    DORFWin = Cells(i, 52).Value
    DORFEnd = Cells(i, 53).Value
    AccWin = Cells(i, 54).Value
    AccEnd = Cells(i, 55).Value


    fname = Cells(i, 44).Value & ".xlsx"

    If Dir(SavePath & "\" & fname) = "" Then
        'Filename does not exist, then use template
        Set dst = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Smart1.xlsx")
    Else
        'File already exists, then use existing & update
        Set dst = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=SavePath & "\" & fname)
    End If

    With dst.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("a2").Value = Name
        .Range("B2").Value = PSFFAll
        .Range("C2").Value = CLSFall
        .Range("D2").Value = CLSWin
        .Range("E2").Value = CLSEnd
        .Range("F2").Value = WWRFall
        .Range("G2").Value = WWRWin
        .Range("H2").Value = WWREnd
        .Range("I2").Value = DORFWin
        .Range("J2").Value = DORFEnd
        .Range("K2").Value = AccWin
        .Range("L2").Value = AccEnd
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dst.Close True, SavePath & "\" & fname
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error Resume Next


Next C
```

End Sub